# "rest_framework CSRF token failed" but it's already set in the request header as "X-CSRF-Token"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-csrf

Already checked other topics and tried the answered solutions but the problem stays still. My put/post requests are return with an error.

> detail: "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."

Although I am sending CSRFToken inside the header `axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = CSRF_TOKEN;`

And there it is the CSRF

[image]

By the way, in **settings.py** I set the authentication classes

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',

],
```

Additionally **views.py**

```
class ProjectViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

  permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated | IsSuperUser]

  # retrieve works without a problem
  def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
    queryset = Project.objects.all().filter(company_user=self.request.user)
    project = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
    serializer = ProjectSerializer(project)
    return Response(serializer.data)

  def update(self, request, pk=None):
    # CSRF request problem
    pass

  def partial_update(self, request, pk=None):
    # CSRF request problem
    pass
```

and **urls.py**

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('project', views.ProjectViewSet, basename='project')

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Do I missing something here? Why do I keep having the **CSRF** error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **`X-CSRFToken`** instead of `X-CSRF-Token`

Comment: it's worked! thank you. will accept it as an answer